# How to get URL out of href that is itself a hyperlink?

Tags: python, html, xpath

I'm using Python and lxml to try to scrape [this html page](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~mstemper2/Math/Pinter/Chapter02). The problem I'm running into is trying to get the URL out of this hyperlink text "Chapter02a". (Note that I can't seem to get the link formatting to work here).

```
<li><a href="[Chapter02A](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~mstemper2/Math/Pinter/Chapter02A)">Examples of Operations</a></li>
```

I have tried

```
//ol[@id="ProbList"]/li/a/@href
```

but that only gives me the text "Chapter02a".

Also:

```
//ol[@id="ProbList"]/li/a
```

This returns a lxml.html.HtmlElement'object, and none of the properties that I found in the documentation accomplish what I'm trying to do.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

chapter_req = requests.get('https://www.math.wisc.edu/~mstemper2/Math/Pinter/Chapter02')
chapter_html = html.fromstring(chapter_req.content)
sections = chapter_html.xpath('//ol[@id="ProbList"]/li/a/@href')
print(sections[0])
```

I want *sections* to be a list of URLs to the subsections.

Comment: just combine the base url `https://www.math.wisc.edu/~mstemper2/Math/Pinter/` and the different part like `Chapter02`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return you are seeing is correct because `Chapter02a` is a "relative" link to the next section.  The full url is not listed because that is not how it is stored in the html.

To get the full urls you can use:

```
url_base = 'https://www.math.wisc.edu/~mstemper2/Math/Pinter/'
sections = chapter_html.xpath('//ol[@id="ProbList"]/li/a/@href')
section_urls = [url_base + s for s in sections]
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense that it's the relative link to the next section. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the concatenation directly at the `XPATH` level to regenerate the URL from the relative link:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

chapter_req = requests.get('https://www.math.wisc.edu/~mstemper2/Math/Pinter/Chapter02')
chapter_html = html.fromstring(chapter_req.content)
sections = chapter_html.xpath('concat("https://www.math.wisc.edu/~mstemper2/Math/Pinter/",//ol[@id="ProbList"]/li/a/@href)')
print(sections)
```

**output:**

```
https://www.math.wisc.edu/~mstemper2/Math/Pinter/Chapter02A
```